# Tie line width to map scale by a formula?

Tags: qgis, line, style

I will explain it by an example :
In scale 8000 the width of a road is 2 mm = 16 map units.
If I use the unit mm, then width at any scale will be 2 mm.
In scale 32000 I find a width of 2 mm is too much.
If I instead use the unit map units, then the width at any scale will be 16 map unis.
In scale 32000 the width will be  16 map units = 0,5 mm, which I find too small.
In scale 32000 I want a width of 1 mm.
This I could get, if I could calculate the width by a formula :
width = sqrt(32000/scale) mm
Is that possible in QGIS ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build an expression in the line width setting that would look like this:

```
sqrt(32000/@map_scale )
```

**@map_scale** is a variable in the expression builder, and **sqrt** is a function available in there as well.